# AJAX not working on localhost

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm trying to get an AJAX example working but i'm unable to get it working. Are you able to run it on XAMPP fine?

I've three files, message.txt, index.html, ajaxtest.js. When you click on the hyperlink it should bring up a pop up with the contents of message.txt. (all files are in the same directory)

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html>
  <head>
  <title> Using XMLHttpRequest</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="ajaxtest.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>
      <a href="message.txt" onclick="grabFile(this.href); return false;">
Click here
</a>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

ajaxtest.js

```
function getHTTPObject() {
  var xhr = false;
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {  //see if a XMLHttpRequest exists
    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();  //if it exists change "xhr" to a new instance of the object
  }
  else if (window.ActiveXObject) {  //see if ActiveX exists (for IE)
    try {  //Allows newer versions of IE to use the newer ActiveX object
      xhr = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.AMLHTTP");  //if it exists change "xhr" to a new instance of the object
    }
    catch(e) { //catches an error and resets "xhr" to false
      try {  //Allows older versions of IE to fall back onto the older version using "try...catch"
        xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");  //if it exists change "xhr" to a new instance of the object
      }
      catch(e) {
        xhr = false;
      }
    }
  }
  return xhr;
}

function grabFile(file) {
  var request = getHTTPObject();
  if (request) {
    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
      displayResponse(request);
    };
    request.open("GET", file, true);
    request.send(null);
  }
}

function displayResponse(request) {
  if (request.readyState == 4) {
    if (request.status == 200 || request.status == 304) {
      alert(request.responseText);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: At the moment when you click on the link it is acting exactly like that and taking me to a new page with the contents of the message.txt file

Comment: What is the error you get in the console?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Do you get an error message? What's the intended behavior/gotten behavior?

Comment: Sorry I don't know what you mean by the console?

As I stated in my question it should bring up a pop up with the contents of the text file and I stated in a previous comment at the moment it is taking me to a new page with the contents of the text file. No error message appears

Comment: I just copied the code and ran it. Aside from getting a 404 error on message.txt, it worked as expected. The link was not followed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I have tried with your example , your request object is not hitting state 4 and using again .
check request.status before the below code, its getting 0 value always . And that's why you script is not alerting response .

```
if (request.status == 200 || request.status == 304) {
  alert(request.responseText);
}
```

Check this for your solutions : http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-ajaxintro3/

Hope that help .

Answer (score 4):

For security reasons JavaScript's access to the file system on the client is restricted! you can [read more here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript#Security)

If you are using google chrome you have to startup the executable with `-allow-file-access-from-files` command:

```
chrome.exe -allow-file-access-from-files
```

There might be a similar configuration for FireFox

Update:
reviewing your code, i figures you are comparing `request.status` against `OK`(200), and `Not Modified` (304) headers! These are HTTP response headers returned from a web server, so when you run the code on a web server you **must** check response headers, otherwise, when running locally using `file:///` protocol you always get `0` as for the response header

Here's a workaround, you can check the domain, if you are running locally then no need to check for response status:

```
function displayResponse(request) {
  if (request.readyState == 4) {
    if (!document.domain || request.status == 200 || request.status == 304) {
      alert(request.responseText);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: How do I do in Linux? I've tried entering "google-chrome -allow-file-access-from-files" in the terminal but when I click the link I still have the problem where instead of a popup with the contents appearing I get brought to another page with the file contents.

Comment: you need to close all instances of google chrome before executing new command line

Comment: Just tested, on a windows command line, `start chrome.exe -allow-file-access-from-files` works just fine

Comment: When I try running that command in the terminal the link stops working altogether.

Comment: It doesn't stop working, it is returning with `status=0`, comment out the line of code that checks the status and you'll get the result

Comment: If I comment out that line it just goes back to sending me another page with the contents rather than a popup with the contents.

Comment: Thanks for that. The problem now is that I get a blank popup and then it takes me to a new page with the contents of the file. I'm assuming this relates to what Vik said about the readystate being 0?